# What does "us or them" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Pulp Fiction (1994)*, Pumpkin says to Honey Bunny about difficulties in robbing liquor stores
which owned by foreigners:

> Pumpkin: We keep on, one of these g**k fuckers gonna make us kill him.
>
> Honey Bunny: I'm not gonna kill anybody.
>
> Pumpkin: I don't want to either. But they'll probably put us in a
> situation  where it's **us or them**.

What does "us or them" mean?

I know the meaning of "us and them" (or) "them and us".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that either the robbers (us) or the people being robbed (them) are going to be killed. That is Pumpkin's excuse for killing the people being robbed.